# CSS Class and Element Selection

Tags: css

Could someone explain the difference between,

```
.class p {..}
```

Versus,

```
p.class {...}
```

Are they both equivalent ways to make the CSS apply to a class .class and P tag? Or is there some functional difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.class p` is anything with a class of "class" **containing** a paragraph tag.

`p.class` is a paragraph tag with a class of "class"

Comment: It should be obvious from this example that "class" is not a good name for a class.

Comment: It should also be obvious that it was worded that way for clarity as pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that

- the first selector apply to paragraphs inside elements having the class "class"
- the second selectorapply to paragraphs which have the class "class"

The first selector apply to the internal p here :

```
<someElement class="class">
     doesn't apply outside p
     <p>apply inside p</p>
</someElement>
```

The second selector apply to this :

```
<p class="class">selector 2</p>
```

[CSS selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reviewing the [w3c spec on selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

`.class p` selects all paragraph element descendants of elements that have a class of `class`

`p.class` selects all paragraph elements that *have* the class `class`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one .class p{} will look for a

The second one p.class{} will look for a